# How many people who participate here on Writing SE have become successful authors?

Tags: young-author

I'm not asking for an exact figure, but I just want a rough idea of how well the people here have done. (I know the definition of successful varies, so I'm just going to use successful as a term for someone who's written something which has sold at least a thousand copies).

Comment: Your first question might be answered here: https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1364/what-have-our-users-published. Your second question is, as you suspect, too broad (and the part about writer's block has also already been asked: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/help-ive-got-writers-block)

Comment: *Really* successful authors I'm afraid you won't find any here on Writing SE, and even if you do, it's unlikely that they would speak up here. What we have here are people with a good technical knowledge about writing. Just as it's very difficult to find any writing professor that made any significant success with their writing.

Comment: For your second questions I recalled something i asked last year: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/30256/common-mistakes-made-by-first-time-fantasy-novelists And, FWIW, I'd add 'Include a moral dimension that the protagonist adheres to throughout; a moral dilemma that defines his journey or decision.; That's the single one thing I wish I had done up front and will always do from here on out. (More broadly, new writers use shortcuts - This is what tropes are, cliches, adverbs, telling-not-showing ... All these are shortcuts. Lazy shortcuts. It's why they're the mark of inexperience.)

Comment: You are right, this question is too broad, but apparently I can't vote to close it while there is an open bounty. I've sold more than 1000 copies of a book. There is no such thing as writer's block. There is such a thing as not having anything to say. If you have something to say, start writing it down. When you get stuck, ask a specific questions about the thing you are stuck on. If you are stuck on basic structure, read a book on story structure such as McKee's _Story_ or Vogler's _Writer's Journey_.

Comment: @Sescepitus Thanks for the bounty 

Comment: @MarkBaker Would it be possible for you to post your comment as answer? (as it seems unlikely that someone will answer and it'd be a shame for Sescepitus' rep to go to waste)

Comment: @Adi219 - Hi Adi, these are good questions, but SE format does not support multiple questions posted as one.  Please separate this into at least two separate questions.  You can keep your first question here, since it already has an answer.  Please edit out the second question and post it separately.  I would also rephrase the second question as "What do you wish you had known before publishing your first book?"  I think you could get some strong answers to that one. EDIT: Just noticed Cloudchaser added an answer to question 2 --that could also be moved to a new post if one is made...

Comment: Note: I'm willing to match Sescepitus' bounty on the new question if it is made (since I don't know which half of the question appealed to him)....

Comment: @ChrisSunami Sure! I'll (hopefully) do it tomorrow 

Comment: @ChrisSunami I have taken the liberty to [open that question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/35407/what-is-the-most-fundamental-piece-of-advice-when-it-comes-to-writing) and have already moved the second part of my answer over to it. I'm looking forward to *your* answer, Chris!

Comment: @Secespitus I have split the question. If you feel that the current question no longer reflects what you want to award a bounty to, please roll back and maybe edit yourself.

Comment: @Cloudchaser No worries, you'll get the bounty (thanks for the hard work). I'll just leave it up a bit to give you some more exposure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the site's users rather than the topic of writing.  (I decided to let the bounty finish since it was almost over when I came across the question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since we don't have sales figures for our published members, I define (probable) "success" as:

1. having two or more books non-self-published

   Publishers usually don't publish a second book by an author unless the first was a financial success, so a second non-self-published book is at least an indicator for probable success.
2. having one book non-self-published

   No matter the eventual sales of a book, if an author has convinced a publisher to sign a contract with them, that author has managed something that the majority of aspiring writers never achieve, and has therefore at least had partial success.
3. having self-published a number of books

   Few writers continue self-publishing if their first one or two books find no readers. So a number of self-published books suggest that some of them must at least have had some moderate success.

Given this definition of three levels of success, I went over the site and looked for it. Below is what I found.

---

Users (that I could find) who have stated either in posts or in their profile that they have published two or more books through a publisher:

- [Clover](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/22482)
- [Rachel](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/14213)
- [Ralph Gallagher](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/361) (fiction)
- [Duncan McKenzie](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/16571) (fiction, [tv screenplays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duncan_McKenzie_(writer)))
- [Kate S.](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/1579) (fiction) – *self-published or non-self-published?*
- [Ray Salemi](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/29073) (fiction)
- [Zachary K](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/1936) (programming)
- [Jim Kyle](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/21464) (electronics)
- [Mark Baker](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/16226) (non-fiction/technical)
- [mlanger](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/226) (technical)
- [Ryan Bigg](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/943) (programming)
- [TomOnTime](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/5320) (system administration)
- [robertc](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/5384) (programming)
- [jimbojw](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/5475) (programming)
- [Mike McCallister](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/11500) (programming)
- [Michael J. Tobias](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/12664) (non-fiction)
- [Michael Kay](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/24574) (programming)
- [Thomas Hunt](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/28477) (non-fiction)
- [Negrino](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/1204) (programmming)
- [Lynn Beighley](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/1679) (programming)
- [Magnus Lie Hetland](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/5854) (programming)
- [Bob Aiello](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/24962) (programming)
- [Dryle Tatum](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/6357) (business)
- [ForEachLoop](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/29738) (programming)
- [anthonygore](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/8600) (programming)

One book through a publisher:

- [Zan700](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/29796) (fiction)
- [Tom Au](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/4599) (investing)
- [Alasdair McAndrew](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/11553) (mathematics)
- [mitatur](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/2641) (history)
- [Chad Cooper](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/3241) (geographic information systems)
- [Chris Sunami](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/10479) (fiction)
- [JonDiPietro](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/642) (technology)
- [SQLRockstar](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/725) (programming)
- [keithjgrant](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/920) (programming)
- [Lou Franco](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/5482) (programming)
- [Tone Milazzo](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/24679) (fiction)
- [reden](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/28745) (programming)
- [Ed Guiness](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/1305) (programming)
- [jonesy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/1313) (programming)
- [Brian Rasmussen](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/1735) (programming)
- [tugberk](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/2138) (programming)
- [DyZ](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/29726) (programming)
- [Steven Lemmens](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/25954) (programming)
- [geerlingguy](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/6771) (programming)
- [sm4](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/14464) (programming)
- [Adam Lynch](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/2635) (programming)
- [ottodidakt](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/2698) (programming)
- [Gregory Brown](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/3841) (programming)
- [Raghav Sood](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/4133) (programming)

Users who have self-published multiple works (number of sales unknown):

- [Steven Drennon](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/2343) (fiction)
- [Dale Hartley Emery](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/272) (fiction)
- [Strozykowski](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/57) (fiction)
- [Norah Deay](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/27471) (fiction and non-fiction)
- [Neil D'Silva](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/11490) (fiction)
- [Danielle Ackley-McPhail](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/6101) (fiction)
- [Rob Bignell](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/6226) (non-fiction)
- [Leonie Mateer](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/26322) (fiction and non-fiction)
- [John Chapman](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/26641) (fiction)
- [Reshwity](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/22620) (fiction)
- [Thaddeus Howze](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/3739) (fiction)
- [Virginia Llorca](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/11420) (fiction)
- [Scott Marlowe](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/858) (fiction)
- [Yvonne Aburrow](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/18615) (non-fiction)
- [EJF](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/18840) (fiction)
- [Adam Dreece](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/19534) (fiction)
- [B. Clay Shannon](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/13810) (fiction)
- [Lee Carlon](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/14000) (fiction)
- [phoe47nix](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/29480) (fiction)
- [Lance Kind](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/14612) (fiction)
- [Justin Jackson](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/8270) (marketing)
- [Jane Smith](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/22035) (fiction)
- [Raymond M Rose](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/22261) (fiction)

---

It is interesting to note that almost all of the self-published authors write fiction, while the vast majority of the non-self-published authors write non-fiction, specifically software-related ("programming").

We also have a few users each who have professionally published short fiction, poems, journalism, and scientific papers, a few technical writers (who don't "publish", or not "books"), and a few professional editors (who do not publish their own writing), but you asked about "books", so I didn't include them in the list.

There may be a few more professional authors on this site who have chosen to remain anonymous (or who haven't given their credentials in their profiles), but compared to the total number of members (currently 22,583) it is clear that this is largely an amateur community.

---

**Note**

If you want on the list above or if I have filed you under the wrong category, post a comment and tell me which of the three categories you belong to. You don't have to provide proof, but if you want you can let us know what kind of book(s) you have published.

"Programming" here means anything from using Wordpress to System Administration.

*Disclaimer*

This list is what I gleaned from how people represent themselves on this site or on their websites. That information may be incomplete or I may have made a mistake. This list is not meant to represent anyone's ability as a writer or otherwise, merely as an indirect indicator for our level of communal knowledge. The order of names on the list has no meaning and is merely a result of my search strategy.

---

I have moved my answer to Adi219's second question (now edited out) to this new question:

- [What is the most fundamental advice when it comes to writing?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/35407/what-is-the-most-fundamental-advice-when-it-comes-to-writing)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is actually quite helpful  so I'll accept this tomorrow unless another answer is posted which I like more

Comment: It's worth noting that many of the high rep answers are from a small subset of the users, and that many of those people do in fact have professional experience, as detailed above.